# Condense two regular expressions into one

Tags: ruby, regex

Is it possible to condense the following two regular expressions into a single one?

```
text = File.read('text.txt')
text.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').gsub(/[^a-z ]/, '')
```

The intention here is to *remove*:

1. All white space characters except for a single space.
2. All none a-to-z characers except for apostrophes.

I tried this:

```
text.gsub(/[^a-z]\s+/, ' ')
```

But I still see line breaks.

**EDIT**

Input

```
Hi    this is cool.
Yes, it's marvelous. 

Lovely.
```

Output

> Hi this is cool Yes it's marvelous Lovely

Comment: All whitespace except a single one is: `\s\s+` or `\s{2,}` (literally, two or more). However, you seem to don't want to remove them. I think you want to squash them into single one, right?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl yes. I only one to keep a single space between each word, no matter what the space is (a new line, line break, etc...)...

Comment: @ChrisWesseling sorry for not being clear. The result will be words only separated by single spaces, case insensitive.

Comment: Can't be combined as is, they're mutually exclusive. It can be done using a single regex and a  callback though. This might shave some time if you're concerned by performance.

Comment: Why do you want to combine them? They're more readable separate

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton I think you missed the final '.' in you expected output.

Comment: Your example output does not match your stated intentions. Just stick with your original two gsubs. Your intentions and the expected result is much clearer.

Comment: @Max I agree. I think I just confused myself even more with  question. But thanks anyway, because your regex was helpful. So in the end I learned a few things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One difficulty is that you're trying to do two separate tasks: remove characters and condense whitespace. It is easier if you rephrase them to be identical: remove nonalphabetic characters or whitespace preceded by whitespace.

```
text.gsub(/((?<=\s)\s|[^a-z ])/i, '')
```

Note that this fits your stated requirements but does not work with your example, since you turned the first newline into a space (even though it matches the second condition) and you kept the apostrophe even though it is non-alphanumeric.

Comment: +1: but I think you should add the `'` to the exclusions, as the author seems to want to keep it

Comment: I believe "preceded" should be "succeeded". There's no non-alphabetic character preceded by whitespace in "Hello, world!". Oh, and the end of string should be accounted for, too.

Comment: This could leave behind a whitespace. `\s` which could be linebreaks, etc.. Oh, maybe not.

Comment: But, it won't replace multiple linebreaks with a space. So, it just strips when he wants to replace first.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
text.gsub(/[^a-z']+/i, ' ')
```

But you need to remove leading and trailing spaces after. you can do it in one shot:

```
text.gsub(/[^a-z']+/i, ' ').strip!
```

notice: don't forget to add the i modifier if you want to preserve uppercase letters.

Comment: That does not remove non a-z characters. I'm still seeing punctuation chracters.